# Is there a polynomial algorithm to solve a dominating set problem given that the input has a dominating set of size $k$.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Is there a polynomial time algorithm to solve a dominating set problem on a directed graph given that the input has a dominating set of size $k$ (Your output set may exceed $k$, and the $k$ is just prior knowledge)? I know that for a tournament, there exists a dominating set of size no more than $\log n + 1$, but
the graph may not be a tournament.

Comment: I thought that the dominating set problem consists in deciding whether a dominating of size $\le$ a given input exists? Then what do you mean with "Your output may exceed $k"?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Now I understand how to do it. Just apply a greedy algorithm and we can prove that $ans < k\log n$